# Error al publicar app en play store hecha con Expo - React Native

Tags: react-native, google-play, expo, google-play-console

Bueans tardes, les agradezco de antemano sus respuestas, termine una app e-commerce hecha en react native y Expo pero al momento de general el aab con el comando expo build:adroid, firmarlo correctamente y subir la app al play store me sale esto:

> *El SDK Segment Analytics Android (com.segment.analytics.android:analytics) 4.9.4 recoge datos personales o sensibles que pueden incluir, entre otros, identificadores Advertising ID, Android ID. Los identificadores de dispositivos persistentes no pueden vincularse a otros datos de usuario personales o sensibles ni a identificadores de dispositivo que se puedan cambiar, tal como se describe en la política de Datos de Usuario.
> No puedes publicar esta versión por un problema con esta política. Para poder publicarla, te recomendamos que cambies a otro SDK, retires este SDK o, si tu proveedor de SDKs ofrece la opción, actualices este SDK a una versión que cumpla la política y no contenga el código infractor.
> De acuerdo con la información proporcionada por tu proveedor de SDKs, te recomendamos que actualices a 4.10.1. Ponte en contacto con el proveedor de SDKs para obtener más información.
> ACTION REQUIRED: Upload a new compliant version AND deactivate the noncompliant version.
> Lee la política de Datos de Usuario para ver más detalles. Consulta cómo enviar una aplicación actualizada para que la revisen aquí.*

Realmente no logro entender de que trata este error ya que no estoy usando ninguna analitica, este es mi package.json

```html
{
  "main": "node_modules/expo/AppEntry.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "expo start",
    "android": "expo start --android",
    "ios": "expo start --ios",
    "web": "expo start --web",
    "eject": "expo eject"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@react-native-async-storage/async-storage": "~1.15.0",
    "@react-native-community/masked-view": "^0.1.11",
    "@react-navigation/bottom-tabs": "^5.11.3",
    "@react-navigation/material-bottom-tabs": "^5.3.11",
    "@react-navigation/native": "^5.9.0",
    "@react-navigation/stack": "^5.13.0",
    "expo": "^44.0.0",
    "expo-linear-gradient": "~11.0.3",
    "expo-payments-stripe": "~8.4.0",
    "expo-status-bar": "~1.2.0",
    "formik": "^2.2.6",
    "jwt-decode": "^3.1.2",
    "react": "17.0.1",
    "react-dom": "17.0.1",
    "react-native": "0.64.3",
    "react-native-dropdown-picker": "^3.8.0",
    "react-native-gesture-handler": "~2.1.0",
    "react-native-keyboard-aware-scroll-view": "^0.9.3",
    "react-native-paper": "^4.7.0",
    "react-native-paper-dropdown": "^1.0.7",
    "react-native-reanimated": "~2.3.1",
    "react-native-root-toast": "^3.2.1",
    "react-native-safe-area-context": "^3.3.2",
    "react-native-screens": "^3.10.1",
    "react-native-snap-carousel": "^3.9.1",
    "react-native-vector-icons": "^7.1.0",
    "react-native-web": "0.17.1",
    "stripe-client": "^1.1.5",
    "yup": "^0.32.8"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.12.9",
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-unicode-property-regex": "^7.16.7"
  },
  "private": true
}
```

Este es mi app.json

```html
{
  "expo": {
    "name": "Estragos",
    "slug": "estragos",
    "version": "1.0.3",
    "orientation": "portrait",
    "icon": "./assets/icon.png",
    "splash": {
      "image": "./assets/splash.png",
      "resizeMode": "contain",
      "backgroundColor": "#161D31"
    },
    "updates": {
      "fallbackToCacheTimeout": 0
    },
    "assetBundlePatterns": [
      "**/*"
    ],
    "ios": {
      "supportsTablet": true,
      "bundleIdentifier": "app.hubtech.estragos",
      "buildNumber": "1"
    },
    "android": {
      "package": "app.hubtech.estragos",
      "permissions": ["ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"],
      "versionCode": 3,
      "adaptiveIcon": {
        "foregroundImage": "./assets/adaptive-icon.png",
        "backgroundColor": "#FFFFFF"
      }
    },
    "web": {
      "favicon": "./assets/favicon.png"
    }
  }
}
```

Estuve buscando este error en internet pero no logro entender de donde se pega ese SDK Segment Analytics Android, si es al momento de ejecutar expo build:android o que pasa ??

Comment: [Te dejo](https://www.ionos.es/digitalguide/paginas-web/desarrollo-web/software-development-kit/) información sobre lo que es un SDK (software development kit). En el resultado te indica que debes actualizar tu versión (tienes la 4.9.4 y debes actualizar a la 4.10.1)

Comment: Creo que no me hice entender, conozco que es un SDK, ahora bien, dentro del desarrollo que hice uso Expo - React Native, dentro de la documentación de estas dos herramientas no veo que usen **El SDK Segment Analytics Android**

Answer (score 0):

generé actualizaciones en el Android Studio, y actualicé la versión de expo a la 45.0.0 e hice la respectiva actualización de las dependencias, con ello pude solucionar ese error.